# Structure instance property value

Tags: swift

I can update property value of class instance using dot notation However It doesn't work for structure.

Here is example:

```
struct Resolution {
    var width = 0

}

class VideoMode {
  var interlaced = false
 }


let someResolution = Resolution()
let someVideoMode = VideoMode()
```

For class:

```
someVideoMode.interlaced // false
someVideoMode.interlaced = true //true
someVideoMode.interlaced // now true
```

For Struct :

```
 someResolution.width // 0
 someResolution.width  = 200 // throws an error says : someResolution is constant
```

**Question is :**

someResolution and someVideoMode  both are constants.
 I can change the property value of class instance without error not saying someVideoMode is constant.However 
 I can not change the property value of struct.It throws an error says someResolution is constant

Why ?

Thank you !

Comment: check `valueOfStructInstance` definition is not `let` because this code compiles without any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct`s are Value types, while `class`es are References.

While you *can* set properties of a constant reference type, you *can not* change the reference itself.

```
let someVideoMode = VideoMode()
someVideoMode = VideoMode()
```

would cause an error.

You can find a detailed description in [the documentation you actually got this sample from](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82).

Comment: Changing let to var fix the problem but in class instance why does it not throw an error ? it is let there too.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much !